# Option type in VB

Tags: vb.net, monads

Is there a `Option` type that we can use in VB? I am working on a project in VB right now and am thinking of a way to get rid off all the `if` check on `null`/`Nothing` and returning of `null`/`Nothing` . 
If i can have something of that sort i could statically ensure that a method returns an `option` instead of surprising callers by returning null .
That would make the code less error prone and would read so much better.

Comment: Can you post a code sample. Do you mean an enumeration? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1.aspx

Comment: No i am not taling anout enums. I am talking about the `Option` type. It is a type that either has something or nothing. It never has null. Basically this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type

Comment: Quick question. How will this reduce the no of if checks? Say, a function was returning null or the required value, and you had one if condition that checked for null. With option type, you will check whether it returns required value or the default value. Unless, I am missing out on something.

Comment: Yeah that probably needs rephrasing . But there will be no surprises. In the sense that the compiler would know that it expects a Option Type. When methods return null it is impossible to confirm statically how the code is going to behave. So basically i can get rid off if checks on nulls and do checks on `Option.get()` .

Comment: Maybe Null-conditional Operators (C# and Visual Basic)?

Comment: I guess people did not understand the question so downvoted instead. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

No.

Long answer:

Support for proper option types, or algebraic data types in general, isn't coming to C# / VB.Net any time soon.

Support for non-nullable types, which aren't quite the same but would still allow compile-time null-checking, is planned for the upcoming C# 7. AFAIK it has not been confirmed yet that VB 15 will include the same feature though.

You can come up with a number of anti-`NullReferenceException` tricks on your own which minimise the chance of accidentally passing a null around, but it's simply not possible to make them 100% compile-time safe for the time being.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Any idea why the negative votes on the question ?

Comment: Not sure, sorry. I haven't been using SO long enough to guess.

Comment: @piaste - I would guess that the question was downvoted because it's not very clear what you are asking.  If there is another language that you know of that has this feature, perhaps you could mention it in the question to help clarify your meaning.